# My Ubuntu 22.04 cannot see some WiFi networks

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, network-manager, ethernet

I have tried this in 2 different houses: I boot my Ubuntu 22.04 and turn on WiFi. Some networks appear (e.g. from neighbors, or the hotspot from my phone), but not the home network (which is visible to other devices e.g. another Ubuntu laptop or my phone). In both cases I needed to firstly connect via cable (in which case the laptop connects to the Internet properly) but upon removing the ethernet cable, my computer does not seem to display the home network as an option.

EDIT:
Command `lspci -nnk |grep -iA3 net` prints:

```bash
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1028:0656]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
08:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] [10de:1341] (rev a2)
```

Comment: Can your Computer handle 5 GHz Wifi or only 2.4 GHz? Maby it's an Hardware problem, not a software problem.

Comment: Pleas edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk |grep -iA3 net`  do you know what channel home wifi is using?

Comment: @Rotstein how could I know that?

Comment: @Jeremy31 I did. The home wifi is 2.4GHz

Comment: Do you know what channel it is using now?    I think you will find it if you switch from auto to a set channel between 1 and 11

Comment: It is channel 10 @Jeremy31

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Sadly it is not, @Jeremy31. The wifi uses channel 10, however I cannot edit this for my PC?